# slow php function putting data in to a large array

Tags: php, sql-server, performance

I have a function that get data from an SQL Server database. The result set is around 5900 records with two columns (`Code` and `Name`) in each record.
However this function can take quite a while to run 2-5 or even longer in some cases.

Here is the code:

```
public function GetAllProductCodes()
{
    $Connection = Database::odbc("sage");
    $sql = "SELECT Code, Name FROM STKStockItemView";
    $ResultSet = Database::execute($Connection, $sql);
    $i = 1;
    $array = array();
    while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($ResultSet)) {
        foreach ($row AS $key => $value) {
            $array[$i][$key] = $row[$key];
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

What would be a more optimum way of running this? Here is a dump of the output array:

```
array (size=5867)
1 => 
array (size=2)
  'Code' => string '0010' (length=4)
  'Name' => string 'Product name' (length=14)
2 => 
array (size=2)
  'Code' => string '0957' (length=4)
  'Name' => string 'Product name' (length=27)
3 => 
array (size=2)
  'Code' => string '0958' (length=4)
  'Name' => string 'Product name' (length=20)
4 => 
array (size=2)
  'Code' => string '1050' (length=4)
  'Name' => string 'Product name' (length=16)
```